# Computational Fluid Dynamics methods

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, boundary-conditions, flow

I have read some articles about the finite difference method on a cartesian orthogonal grid. I understand how it works when Dirichlet boundary conditions are used, or when Neumann boundary conditions are used on a simple boundary (for example the rectangular boundary of the simulation). What I don't understand is how to use the Neumann boundary conditions in boundaries with arbitrary shape (in  a 2-dimensional cartesian orthogonal grid). Suppose I want to simulate the potential flow about a cylinder (in 2D it becomes a circle): can I use the finite difference method on a circular boundary, where that circle has been drawn on the cartesian grid (so it is approximated by a set of little squares)?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am not too clear on what is being asked here. Are you asking if you can generate a boundary fitted orthogonal grid? I believe that the [curvilinear grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates) approach would work well for such a case. The idea is to transform the "irregular" physical domain into a computational space which is regular such as a square (in 2D or cube in 3D). After such transformation applying the boundary conditions and discretization of governing equations is trivial. More [here](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=4971218336788088846&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5)

Answer (score 3):

Its a method called co-ordinate grid transformations that is used to transform an arbitrarily shaped geometry into a square; in the computational domain. Grid transformations work as parametric transformations do, in co-ordinate geometry. what these transformations basically do is, they map the complex geometry (viz. a curve) into a simpler geometry (a line; in the computational domain) for the computer to handle.
[Here's a link](http://kartoweb.itc.nl/geometrics/coordinate%20transformations/coordtrans.html) which mite be useful. A good book on this is [CFD by J. Anderson](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=dJceAQAAIAAJ&q=computation+john+anderson&dq=computation+john+anderson&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aomEUbTHOcKPrQffy4CQDw&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA&safe=active). There's a complete chapter on grid-transformations in this book. A more involved [discussion](http://www.taoxing.net/web_documents/cfdgrid.pdf) on the same topic.